# Getting errors in my char array function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 20;
char correctAnswers(char [], int);
char userAnswers(char [], int);
void compareArray(char[] , char [], int [], int, int &);

int main(){
    char correct[SIZE];
    char userArray[SIZE];
    int result[SIZE];
    int element;

    correctAnswers(correct, SIZE);
    cout << "Please enter the student's answers for each of the questions."  << endl;
    cout << "Press Enter after typing each answer." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter only an A, B, C, or D for each question." << endl;
    userAnswers(userArray, SIZE);
    compareArray(correct, userArray, result, element);

    cout << "Array 1 and Array 2 are different at" << element<<" positions: "   << " ";

    for(int i = 0; i < element; i++)
        cout << result[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}

char correctAnswers(char correct[], int SIZE){
    correct[SIZE] = {'B','D','A','A','A','B','B','A','C','D','B','B','D','A','D','D','A','B','D','A'};
}

char userAnswers(char userArray[], int SIZE){
    userArray[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        cout << "Question " << (i+1) << ":";
        cin >> userArray[i];
        while(userArray[i] != 'A' || userArray[i] != 'B' || userArray[i] != 'C' || userArray[i] != 'D'){
            cout << "Invalid input. Choose A,B,C or D." << endl;
            cin >> userArray[i];
        }
    }
}

void compareArray(char correct[], char userArray[], int result[], int &element){
    int right = 0, wrong = 0;

    element = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(userArray[i] == correct[i]){
            right = right + 1;
        }
        else
            wrong = wrong + 1;
    }

    if(right >= 15){
        cout << "You Passed!";
    }
    else
        cout << "You Fail.";

    cout << "Correct answers = " << right << endl;
    cout << "Incorrect answers = " << wrong << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(userArray[i] != correct[i]){
            result[element] = i+1;
            element++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting 3 errors and can't figure out why. In my char correctAnswers function, I get an error saying "cannot convert from 'braced-init-list' to 'char" and that the initializer contains too many elements. Also, in my last function it tells me function does not take four elements?

Comment: Can you please make your question a bit more clear? If I would be mean I would say Q:"Getting errors?" A: "Yes, you do"

Comment: Is this your real code? `compareArray` is declared to take 5 arguments, yet you pass it only 4.

Answer (score 0):

`correct` in `correctAnswer` is an array of `char`, so `correct[SIZE]` is a *particular* element of that array (although located past the end of the array), which you are trying to assign an array of characters to.

Even if you removed `[SIZE]`, you'd still have a problem, because you are trying to use an *initializer* (which, as the same suggests, is for *initializing*) to make an assignment.

Don't understand what you mean about the *last function* at all.

Comment: The last function is declared with five parameters and defined (well, a different overload is defined past the visibility of `main`) with four.